# Display color legend when data has only one category

Tags: r, legend, r-plotly

I just found out that if a variable is mapped to the `color` argument in `plotly`, the legend is automatically displayed only if the variable has more than one category. This is illustrated below. `df1` has two categories and they are displayed in the legend . `df2`, on the other hand,  has only one category and no legend is displayed. My goal is to display the legend in the `df2` plot.

```
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100,
  y = rnorm(100),
  category = sample(c("cat", "dog"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

plot_ly(
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  data = df1,
  x = ~x,
  y = ~y,
  color = ~category
)
```

[image: plotly with legend]

```
f2 <- data.frame(
   x = 1:100,
   y = rnorm(100),
   category = "dog"
)

plot_ly(
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  data = df2,
  x = ~x,
  y = ~y,
  color = ~category
)
```

[image: plotly without legend]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a legend with the argument `showlegend`:

```
plot_ly(
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  data = df2,
  x = ~x,
  y = ~y,
  color = ~category
) %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE)
```

[image]